# Mockito return value for specific objects and throw for all other object of same type

Tags: java, mockito, testng

I have the code below:

```
private SaveTransactionClient mockedTransactionClient;

private static Publisher publisher;

private static MyDTO mDTO1;
private static MyDTO mDTO2;
private static MyDTO mDTO3;

@BeforeClass
public void setUp() throws IOException {
    TransactionResponse successResponse = new TransactionResponse();
    successResponse.setDateRequest("2016-04-27 18:47:50");
    successResponse.setResponse("OK");
    successResponse.setTransactionNumber("1");

    TransactionResponse failedResponse = new TransactionResponse();
    failedResponse.setDateRequest("2016-04-27 18:47:50");
    failedResponse.setResponse("Dublicate Transaction Error");
    failedResponse.setTransactionNumber("1");

    mDTO1 = new MyDTO(1, LocalDateTime.now(), 0);
    mDTO2 = new MyDTO(2, LocalDateTime.now(), 0);
    mDTO3 = new MyDTO(3, LocalDateTime.now(), 0);

    mockedTransactionClient = mock(SaveTransactionClient.class);

    when(mockedTransactionClient.sendTransactionRequest(mDTO1)).thenReturn(successResponse);
    when(mockedTransactionClient.sendTransactionRequest(mDTO2)).thenReturn(failedResponse);
    when(mockedTransactionClient.sendTransactionRequest(mDTO3)).thenThrow(new IOException());
    when(mockedTransactionClient.sendTransactionRequest(any(MDTO.class))).thenThrow(new IOException());


    publisher = new publisherImpl(mockedTransactionClient);
}
```

The actual tests are

```
@Test
public void TestOnlyExceptionalPublishing() {
    BlockingQueue<MDTO> mDTOs = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(Arrays.asList(mDTO3));
    assertEquals(mDTOs.size(), 1);

    List<MDTO> successful = publisher.publish(wDTOs);

    assertEquals(successful.size(), 0);
}

@Test
public void TestOneSuccessContainsExceptionalPublishing() {
    BlockingQueue<MDTO> mDTOs = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(Arrays.asList(mDTO3,mDTO1, mDTO2));
    assertEquals(mDTOs.size(), 3);

    List<MDTO> successful = publisher.publish(mDTOs);

    assertEquals(successful.size(), 1);
}
```

Now the `MDTO` is immutable and the way the `publisher.publish(mDTO)` works is that on **Exception** increments a "retries" counter in `MDTO` and retry up to 3 times. When the counter is incremented a new `MDTO` is generated which, with the response *not* being stubbed by Mockito, creates a problem for me. I added the `any` but this makes the other tests fail since it throws for all and not for any OTHER except for the objects I have already supplied.

Is there any **anyOther** type of way to do this in Mockito?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think (if I did understand correctly) that you are looking for [`doAnswer`/`thenAnswer`](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#11):

```
when(mockedTransactionClient.sendTransactionRequest(any(MyDTO.class)).thenAnswer(new Answer<TransactionResponse>() {
   @Override
   public TransactionResponse answer(final InvocationOnMock invocation) {
       final MyDTO arg = invocation.getArgumentAt(0, MyDTO.class)
       // do stuff here based on arg
       return someTransactionResponse; // or throw some exception
   }
});
```

Comment: It says about stabbing void method. I want to dictate what mockito should return if the mocked class' method argument is not one of the three I have already provided.

Comment: re-read the example, in the linked doc, what you return *is returned*

Comment: Yes your example makes it more clear will try it now